# Find if date is the next valid date from today Momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

This is a straight question but I don't find any suitable solution. Given an array of dates, ie 
`['2015-01-01', '2015-04-20', ...]`

Is there any way to check if a item of the array is the next valid date after today? 
I am using `moment.js`.

Answer (score 2):

> […] Is there any way to check if a item of the array is the next valid date after today?

Your description is not really clear to me, but it sounds like you’re trying to programmatically determine if an array of dates contains tomorrow’s date (i.e. “the next valid date after today”). In that case, read on:

First, get tomorrow’s date in the same format as the strings in your array using moment.js:

```
var tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Now you can just loop over the array and compare each value to `tomorrow` using `==` or `===` (doesn’t matter in this case):

```
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  if (date == tomorrow) {
    // Bingo!
  }
});
```

If you just want to check if any of the dates in the array are tomorrow’s date, use `Array#some`:

```
var containsTomorrow = dates.some(function(date) {
  return date == tomorrow;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt has to be that the next valid date is for tomorrow. If the array contains 2015-04-25 and not 2015-04-21 it wont return anything. and 25th is the next valid date from today inside the array

Comment: No, what I want is to get the next date from today in the array. Not that the next day is tomorrows date or not.

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be solved without using momentjs

```
var todaysDate = new Date();
var min;
var index;
var array = ['2015-01-01', '2015-04-20', ...];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var inputDate = new Date(array[i]);
    var ts = inputDate - todaysDate;
    if (!min || (ts < min && ts > 0) ) {
        min = ts;
        index = i;
    }
}
// index will contain the index of the nearest next date
```